# extract usernames or email/domain after @ sign

Tags: regex

I have a file with a list of usernames and email addresses and I need two expressions. One to get the email addresses (they always end in .com or .net or .org) and one to get the usernames.

I only want the usernames as one expression and domain portions as the other, I don't want the `@` sign.

```
@stackoverflow.com
@google.com
@example.com
```

I tried

```
^@.*?..*?$
```

Users

```
@Perl
@Python
@PHP
```

I tried

```
^@.*?$
```

Any suggestions are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first expression, it would match if you escaped the dot `\.` before the last `.*?` Your second expression is just clearly matching the whole lines. To match but exclude the `@` you could do..

For the domains use:

```
^@(\S+\.[^\s]+)$
```

Regular expression:

```
^             the beginning of the string
@             '@'
 (            group and capture to \1:
\S+           non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)      
\.            '.'
[^\s]+        any character except: whitespace (1 or more times)
)             end of \1
$             before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/vR0cF4)

For the users use:

```
^@([^\s.]+)$
```

Regular expression:

```
^             the beginning of the string
@             '@'
 (            group and capture to \1:
[^\s.]+       any character except: whitespace or '.' (1 or more times)
)             end of \1
$             before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/tR2hI7)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for domains:

```
^@[^.]+\.[^.]+$
```

This will match the start of the string, followed by an `@`, followed by one or more of any character *other than* `.`, followed by a `.`, followed by one or more of any character *other than* `.`, followed by the end of the string.

But this will not capture domains with more than two parts (e.g. `@meta.stackoverflow.com`). If that's important you might try this instead:

```
^@[^.]+(\.[^.]+)+$
```

This will match the start of the string, followed by an `@`, followed by one or more of any character *other than* `.`, followed by a group which consists of a `.`, followed by one or more of any character *other than* `.`, where this group may be repeated repeated one or more times, followed by the end of the string.

And this for users:

```
^@[^.]+$
```

This will match the start of the string, followed by an `@`, followed by one or more of any character *other than* `.`, followed by the end of the string.

Comment: this is matching the @ on the next lines?

Answer (score 0):

try this

**USERS**
    (?<=@)\w+

**EMAIL**
    (?<=@)\w+.(?:com|net|org)

EDIT:
uhm you didn't stipulate what regex engine you're running on, this is pcre based, but any engine with lookbehind most likely will have the same syntax